# React Native initialises with empty folder

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

I'm branching out into the world of React Native and am completely green on how to set up a new project.

Having followed the documentation to the letter, I'm still getting an empty folder with only a `project.json` file inside when I call `create-react-native-app init MyProject`.

I'm using PowerShell in admin mode on a Windows 10 x64 box. What sort of things should I try and look for to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Is create-react-native-app init MyProject some sort of starter kit for RN? 
Instead you could just install **react-native cli** globally and initialize a new project by react-native init MyProject as per official [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.24/docs/getting-started.html#quick-start)

Comment: @Hariks Yeah, it's this basically: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app.html

Comment: I tried out that and it seems to be working fine will all required files, it took few minutes though. It seems to be using yarn as package manger. Try installing [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#windows-tab) first

Comment: @Hariks Christ. Is that really where we're at as a software community now? I'll have a go but I seriously hope we don't need package manager managers to be aligned perfectly in order to just get started.